# Perl sorting an array of references to arrays

Tags: perl, sorting, reference

I am relatively new to Perl.  I have a reference to an array called $TransRef that contains references to arrays.  My goal is to write a sub that takes the $TransRef arguement as its only argument, sorts the references to the underlying array by the 2nd element (a string) and sets the output back to the $TransRef reference.  Can someone please show how this can be done in Perl?

Here is some code that generates $TransRef.  It has not been tested yet and may have some bugs:

```
# Parse the data and move it into the Transactions container.
for ($Loop = 0; $Loop < 5; $Loop++)
{
   $Line = $LinesInFile[$Loop];
   # Create an array called Fields to hold each field in $Line.
   @Fields = split /$Delimitor/, $Line;  
   $TransID = $Fields[2];
   # Save a ref to the fields array in the transaction list.
   $FieldsRef = \@Fields;
   ValidateData($FieldsRef);
   $$TransRef[$Loop] = $FieldsRef;
}
SortByCustID($TransRef);

sub SortByCustID()
{
   # This sub sorts the arrays in $TransRef by the 2nd element, which is the cust #.
   # How to do this?
   my $TransRef = @_;
   ...
}
```

Comment: How about some code?? What have you tried till yet?

Comment: Show the data structure you are talking about.

Comment: TLP: the description seemed pretty complete and unambiguous.  Unusual, I know :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty straightforward:

```
sub sort_trans_ref {
    my $transRef = shift;
    @$transRef = sort { $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] } @$transRef;
    return $transRef;
}
```

though it would be more natural to me to not modify the original array:

```
sub sort_trans_ref {
    my $transRef = shift;
    my @new_transRef = sort { $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] } @$transRef;
    return \@new_transRef;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That looks like it should work.  I chose your answer as the solution since you were first to answer.

Comment: Also, I guess that your suggestion of returning the reference to the newly sorted data is probably a better way to do it since it makes the code more modular.

Answer (score 2):

```
sub string_sort_arrayref_by_second_element {

  my $param = shift;
  @$param = sort { $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] } @$param;

}
```