# Sorting an array of array references in Perl

Tags: perl, sorting

#### Synopsis

I'm trying to sort an array of array references based on the arrays' second element.

For example, I would like to sort the following arrays, in `@array` into another, sorted array:

```
632.8 5
422.1 4
768.6 34
```

This is the end array, `@sorted_array`

```
422.1 4
632.8 5
768.6 34
```

#### Attempted Code

I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12590318/perl-sorting-an-array-of-references-to-arrays) and have modified it slightly. However, I receive an error: `Use of uninitialized value in print at .\test.pl line 17` when I try to dereference the sorted array.

```
#!/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = ();
foreach my $i (0..10) {
    push @array, [rand(1000), int(rand(100))];
}

foreach my $i (@array) {
    print "@$i\n";
}
print "================\n";

my $sorted_ref = sort_arr(\@array);
print @$sorted_ref;

sub sort_arr {
    my @arr = @$_[0];
    my @sorted_arr = sort { $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] } @arr;
    return \@sorted_arr;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're passing an array reference into the subroutine and then trying to use it as an array. You need to dereference it first.

```
sub sort_arr {
    my ($arr) = @_;
    my @sorted_arr = sort { $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] } @{ $arr };
    return \@sorted_arr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I thought I was dereferencing it with `my @arr = @$_[0];`. :p

Comment: @SinTrans It would have worked if you placed `$_[0]` in braces e.g. `my @arr = @{ $_[0] };`

Comment: @SinTrans A side note, you're using `cmp` (string comparison) when the data seems to be numeric. It should probably be `<=>` (numeric comparison) instead.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Thanks!

@AKHolland Yes, but I believe perl managed to figure it out with `cmp` as perl usually decides ambiguous things like that. :D

Comment: @SinTrans: No. Numeric and string comparisons are very different. If Perl could "figure it out" there wouldn't be two operators

Comment: It will seem to work until you end up with a data set like `[1, 2, 36, 4, 50, 6]`.

Comment: @Borodin thanks for sorting everything out (pun intended) :p